# Place interesting tags list in a consistent location

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising, user-interface

A minor gripe with the Interesting Tags display and advertising, specifically on Stack Overflow but probably more generally applicable - sometimes there is a good-sized panel ad in the top right panel, above the interesting tags list, and sometimes there isn't (when not, it might be below the list).  This is when I'm logged in, so it isn't the anonymous/repped user ad level discrepancy.

The result of this is that the Interesting Tags is not in the same location at all times, so grabbing one of my tags is a bit awkward (I have to hunt for the tag list).

OTOH, I understand that the top of the right sidebar is prime ad space.

If the wizards who work on the SO software could somehow invent a solution that keeps the tags in a consistent place without sacrificing advertising needs, I think the resulting UI would be easier to use.  Any great suggestions for how this can be done?

Comment: More of a workaround than a solution, but if you're willing to take one more click, using the logo to reach the front page will always have your interesting tags consistently on the top of the right bar, above the advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

It's been annoying me for a while that I have to scroll down to find the Interesting Tags. Personally, I'm all for this.

The problem comes from when you are used to browse tag by tag. I would click on `python`, for example. When I'm done, I want to click on `opengl`, but the list of my interesting tags is cluttered by the "Related Tags" section.