# Can we have moveable interface Items?

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

I would very much like to have the ability to move items in the right hand column according to my liking and have the state saved for my next login, much like the iGoogle interface.

This is simply because when I drill down into a tag on SO, I would prefer not to have to scroll down past related tags to see my chosen interesting tags.

I wonder if anyone else has had similar thoughts, or thinks this is a good idea?

Comment: A different feature request that might be to your liking might be [this one for consistent location of interesting tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43664/place-interesting-tags-list-in-a-consistent-location).

Comment: Thanks this is another alterantive.

Answer (score 1):

So... you want to turn Stack Overflow into a portal?

Well, it *is* my homepage.....

Comment: No if you read the question you can see the moveable div aspect is a proposal which could improve the user experiance wthin SO (from a navigation perspective), not to adjust the purpose of SO in any way.   The comparison with iGoogle is to illustrate how the movable areas might work.

Comment: @DamienL: movable sections that are saved across visits are typically a feature of portals. It was a poor joke, I guess.