# Customise personal tag sidebar layout?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, design, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place interesting tags list in a consistent location](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43664/place-interesting-tags-list-in-a-consistent-location)

Is it possible to customise the homepage in any way? I find it annoying that my 'favourite tags' move halfway down the page after I click on one.

Original Position:

[image: Original position]

After I choose one, they move down the page, below the related tags section:

[image: After I choose a tag]

I'd like them to remain at the top of the page.

Comment: Well, once you've clicked on a favorites tag you're not longer on the homepage, you're on /questions.

Comment: Borderline... this one is about "favorites" being bumped by "related," that one is about "favorites" being bumped by ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe items in the sidebar should start with content that's most relevant to the page. So for a `/questions` page  it makes more sense to have tags that are relevant to the post appear first, and for the `/questions/tagged/*` to first show info that's relevant to the selected tag.

If you access the Interesting Tags section of the sidebar often then I can see how the change in position can be slightly inconvenient. However, what works best for one person may not necessarily be suitable for the general audience.

> *Is it possible to customise the homepage in any way?  I find it annoying that my 'favourite tags' move halfway down the page after I click on one.*

It's won't be easy convincing the powers that be that interesting tags should always be on top. In the mean time, you can still make the changes locally using Userscripts. I personally user quite a few Userscripts to cater the site to my preferences.

Here's a basic one which pulls the Interesting Tags (if it exists) to the top of the sidebar: [view](https://gist.github.com/1962bd9a83a735e5a337) ([install](https://gist.github.com/raw/1962bd9a83a735e5a337/82aabed1faab8e5eb43777c63fb73abca0c4c2f7/Userscript_SE_personaltags_up.user.js)).

Or, to try it out quickly, simply run the following in a javascript console while you're on a relevant page:

```
$('#interesting-tags').prependTo($('#sidebar'));
```